# How do I pair multiplication across dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-extraction

I want to do feature engineering using multiple numeric features, the idea is do pair multiplication across dataframe, preferred answer is something that available on machine learning library, such as [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf), [Keras](https://keras.io), [TPOT](https://automl.info/tpot/), [H20](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3), etc (I don't know the scientific name of this process), but is fine to do this without library.

Here's my simplified dataset

```
No  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3
1          10         20         30
2          20         30         40
```

Here's what I need

```
No  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_1xfeature2  feature_1xfeature_2  feature_2xfeature_3
1          10         20         30                 200                  300                  600            
2          20         30         40                 600                  800                 1200
```

What I did

```
df['feature_1xfeature2'] =  df['feature_1'] * df['feature_2']
df['feature_1xfeature3'] =  df['feature_1'] * df['feature_3']
df['feature_2xfeature3'] =  df['feature_2'] * df['feature_3']
```

This is prone to mistakes for tons of features. How to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools` to get the product of all columns:

```
import itertools

for col_a, col_b in itertools.product(df.columns, 2):
    df[col_a + 'x' + col_b] = df[col_a] * df[col_b]
```

The `itertools.product(df.columns, 2)` produces all combinations of columns when taken 2 items from df.columns.

#### Edit

Looking at your problem a bit more in detail I think you are better off using `itertools.combinations` instead. This produces not all possible products, but all possible combinations.

Example, assume the columns 'A', 'B', 'C'

`itertools.product` produces ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'C').

`itertools.combinations` produces ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')

Hence, this would work better:

```
import itertools

for col_a, col_b in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df[col_a + 'x' + col_b] = df[col_a] * df[col_b]
```

Comment: so `itertools.product` is usefull for permutation ? if I use subtraction or division

Comment: The `itertools` library was build to efficiently iterate over values. The `itertools.product` method is indeed used to find all permutations. The multiplication in my example code was used as your example, but you could also write this with subtraction or division, e.g. for subtraction: `df[col_a + '-' + col_b] = df[col_a] - df[col_b]`. If you want to do more elaborate stuff with the arrays stored in each column, you could use df['<col_x>'].values and treat it as a `numpy.array` instead. This offers a lot more functionality

Comment: Ok, this is what I need, literally I need both

Answer (score 2):

There are other more specialised ways to do it automatically. E.g. `PolynomialFeatures`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# original data
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 10, 20, 30], [2, 20, 30, 40]], columns = ['No', 'feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3'])

# selecting features to use for features generation
seed_feature_names = ['feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_3']
seed_features = pd.DataFrame(data = df[seed_feature_names], columns=seed_feature_names)

# actual features generation
poly = PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True, include_bias=False)
df_enhanced = pd.DataFrame(data = poly.fit_transform(seed_features), columns=poly.get_feature_names(seed_features.columns))
```